# Enterprise Application Integration specification for software architects

Tags: integration, enterprise

What is a common notation/specification to describe Enterprise Application Integration?
Are there some helpful tools for software architects to design enterprise integration?

Comment: `UML` is a good candidate. You can use [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://sparxsystems.com/) as the tool

Answer (score 3):

The book “Enterprise Integration Patterns: Designing, Building, and Deploying Messaging Solutions (Addison-Wesley Signature Series (Fowler))” by Hohpe and Woolf is fairly definitive and provides the patterns that Apache Camel has implemented.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, thats great book but how about describing the whole IT landscape and all integrations flows? How to manage integration registry?

Comment: For high level connectivity diagrams I tend to use a UML deployment diagram in Enterprise Architect, draw all my nodes and connect them with the appropriate connection pathes - however, EA has a rubbish attempt at drawing a ESB, so if a nice drawing is important visio might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://www.draw.io/.

1. Create a blank diagram.
2. Click more shapes on the bottom left.
3. EIP listed under the "Other" category.

or try Visio EIP stencil http://camel.apache.org/eip.html

Comment: Thanks for draw.io - very useful!